# Using ExpressJS on Server and JQuery on Client static links

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

just started learning jQuery and node.js, and it worked really good. But at this point I found a problem which could not be solved by googleing again and again. It might be very simple, but can't find out...

So here it is:

I am writing my Server in ExpressJS/Node.JS, serving web pages like this to the server:

```
router.get("/", function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});
```

On the client side I request pages with jQuery like this

```
<li><a id="show-catchem" href="#page-content">CatchEm</a></li>
```

and

```
$("#show-catchem").click(
  function() {
    $("#content-page").load("html/catchem.html #page-content");
  }
);
```

This works great, but I'd like to do that jQuery stuff too, when clicking on a link somewhere else like a Link on Facebook:

www.homepage.com/catchem

I can answer this with ExpressJS, but have no idea how to insert it on the Client side into the main page.

Hope I made it clear,
cheers :)

Comment: For this you have to set router for that URL. Otherwise it won't recognize the request.

Comment: yes, thats not the problem router.get("/catchem", function(req, res) {
 res.sendFile(path + "catchem.html");
}); - but how to integrate/inject it into the main page and return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a request to the server, then in the server retrieve the HTML content  and pass it to the client through some view engine like [jade](http://jade-lang.com/). In Jade, in order to inject the html content that is in a variable, you have to use the `!=` operator, which not scape the content. Since in the example I show you below the HTML content is an entire page, I'll inject it to the root of the page, if you want put the content in other place, you need to associate the HTML content to a tag (e.g: attaching the content to a `div` tag, `div!= content`.

Example:

Server

```
// send the HTML content to the client view through responseHTML variable
router.get('/catchem', function(req, res){
    request.get('http://www.google.com', function(err, response, body){
        res.render('catchem', {responseHtml: body});
    });
});
```

Client (catchem.jade page)

```
!= responseHtml
```

Comment: thanks, is this possible without jade? and wouldn't this cause the client to download the whole page every time I click on a link inside the page?

Comment: yes, I just show you how you can inject the HTML content to the client view. You can save the request into a file and then load it with `fs` or using another approach (save in memory), maybe your HTML content are static files that you only need to load instead of use the `request` module. You can use another view engine as well, the only point is figure out how inject (unescape) the content.